# How to fix broken Laravel link to local file system?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We inherited a custom laravel app and in the admin area, a link that points to a file in the local storage has broken:

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at https://domain.tld/admin/donor/1818/document/56/DCCA8ACC-7B1B-4D90-977C-257BDA5AE56E.png might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

These links used to work, so I'm not sure what broke. I've verified that the all folders and files in the app have correct permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the storage public if you didn’t set it up.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) for more details.

Comment: This was in place but I ran it again anyways: `The "public/storage" directory already exists.`

Comment: @PhilipSmith Make sure that the origin file is exist, and it will be helpful if you share the filesystem configuration to know more.